# How to find IP addresses requested when user logs in into web application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, reverse-proxy, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM which hosts an application. Virtual network in which VM is located is connected through VPN to my internal network. The application is open to the internet by Azure connector and setting up a reverse proxy.

User in question is in the same domain as the VM. This user has access only to this VM's IP address. When I try to login to the application using this user it doesn't work he cannot be authenticated. But, when I remove this logon restriction and user has access to all machines in the internal network he can access the application and gets authenticated.

I need to find out which IP addresses this user has to have. I cannot leave him with access to all machines in the internal network I need to specify only the needed ones.

How can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you want this user to access your application via the Internet, you should add this user's public outbound IP address to the logon restriction.

If you want this user to access your application in an internal network or from an on-premise network, you should add this user's private IP address.

Azure VM can be protected by the NSG rules, you can check NSG flow logs to know the current state of the network, who is connecting, where they're connecting from, which ports are open to the internet, expected network behavior, irregular network behavior, and sudden rises in traffic. From **flowTuples**, you can find **source IP** that request to your Azure VM.

For more information, you could read [Introduction to flow logging for network security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-network-configuration-diagnostics-overview).